# javascript: loading bar/wheel while loading composite image

Tags: javascript, image-loading

I have an HTML page with some javascript functions.
It basically does this...
I have some images with transparent backgrounds (.png), I use the z-index property to sovrappose each image to the others so that I can assemble a new image.
With some buttons you can activate the javascript that makes a substitution of some images with the other.

Maybe an example will help you to understand the situation better:
Imagine a car. You have three images: glasses, wheels and body.
Each image has a transparent background so that if you see all the images together you can see the whole car.
With a button you can substitute the wheels image with another wheels image so that you can see more "versions" of the same car without creating an image for every combination (i have 345 possible combinations so this is the only way).

It works very well but it's slow :(
When I have to change only one piece, the substitution happens immediately, but when I have to change many pieces with only one click, it loads the images slowly so that it's a horrible effect.

What I need is a loading bar/wheel that appears over every other image and that disappears when the browser finishes loading the composite image.
I tried to search the web for a solution, but I only find solutions for loading the whole page. But in my case, the page doesn't change, only the inner images change.

How can I resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance,
marco